# Oh-notation above cubic

Tags: time, complexity-theory, notation

I have a question about calculating time-complexity in algorithms.
Is it possible to have a notation such as O(n^4) if you have four nested for-loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, the answer is yes. Four nested loops could (depending on the loops) be O(n<sup>4</sup>).

There are not a lot of polynomial-time algorithms with complexity above cubic, but they do exist. For example, the well-known AKS primality test is O(k<sup>12</sup>) in its original formulation (where k is the length of the input number), though it has been recently reduced to k<sup>7.5</sup>.